# NodeJS Error: header too long at Object.createSecureContext

Tags: node.js, rest, http-post, node-modules, pfx

I am trying to call the REST API with PFX & PassPhrase, but each time I getting 'header too long' error.
My certificate file size is 11kb. Below snippet is working fine for other REST API without pfx, but no success with pfx

```
var options = {
    hostname: '<hostname>',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    pfx: fs.readFileSync(<pfx file path>),
    passphrase: '<passphrase>',
    json: { 'Request': 'My Custom Req'}
};
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function (d) {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

I have ran my application with following command; but still problem persists:

```
node --max-http-header-size=819200 .\restPost.js
```

The REST API is perfectly working and I have tested the same using Postman and .NET Core web client solutions.

Need your help to fix the issue in NodeJS

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener - Do you think this helps?

Comment: Same snippet is used above, it didn't work